# Retain mouse cursor position on touch

Tags: c#, touch, mouse-cursor

I have a customised on screen keyboard which is working well using Visual Studio C# and sendkeys. However the mouse cursor moves to the position of my key press when I touch a key. I would like the cursor to remain in the original position in the notepad window after I touch the keys similar to the windows 10 on screen keyboard so I can use the keyboard and mouse together efficiently. Is there a way I can do this? This is the code that is controlling my keyboard at the moment:

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
        {
            get
            {
                CreateParams param = base.CreateParams;
                param.ExStyle |= 0x08000000;
                return param;
            }
        }
        public Keyboard()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void t_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SendKeys.Send("t");
        }
```